# How to pass a List<string> object from a dialogbox to the main form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I call a form with ShowDialog() from my main form. Instead of passing values one by one from the dialog form, I'd like to pass a list of the values, so that the main form can work with them (depending on the options on the main form, the number of fields on the dialog form differs).

This code, however, crashes my program, but does not throw any exceptions. The problem must be with the list, because this method worked with simple variables.

The dialog form's class contains this:

```
List<string> valuesToReturn;
public List<string> ValuesToReturn { get => ValuesToReturn; set => ValuesToReturn = value; }
```

The dialog form's constructor creates a new instance of the list:

```
valuesToReturn = new List<string>();
```

And then in the event handler (when Enter is pressed) I would like to add the values of all the NoEnterTextBox-es to the list:

```
foreach (object item in this.Controls)
{
    if(item is NoEnterTextBox) {
        valuesToReturn.Add((item as NoEnterTextBox).Text);
    }
}
```

Please help me how to correct this code. Thank you.

Comment: See my two form project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: I did not get the problem, is it the ability to pass values from dialog form to main form or the values you want to add to valuesToReturn list with the foreach loop?

Comment: I want to add the text of all the textboxes (of the dialog form) to the list, then retrieve that list in the main form. Than in the main form, I want to access the elements of that list.

Comment: Does anyone has any idea why my code is not working? I have a suspicion that accessor of the list is causing the problem, I'm confused what does "getting the list" and "setting the list means", does it refers to the whole list, or the elements of it. What's the difference between `ValuesToRetun.Add ` (the accessor with capital) and `valuesToReturn.Add` (the variable itself, which is private)

Answer (score 0):

use the `DialogResult` value of form 2 in order to determine if there is a need to refresh `Form1`. also `HandleList()` method will populate all text boxes `.text` to the list.

calling `Form2` **from** `Form1`:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
                // refresh form
               AddItemsFromListInForm2(f2.valuesToReturn);
            } 
        }

 private void AddItemsFromListInForm2(List<string> valuesToReturn)
 {
     // do something with valuesToReturn...
 }
```

**user presses (OK \ Save) button on `form2`:**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            HandleList();
            this.Close();
        }

   private void HandleList()
   {

        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if(c is TextBox)
            {
                valuesToReturn.Add(c.Text);
            }
        }
   }
```

in another button on `Form2` you can do that piece of code, if there is a case that you dont want to refresh Form1:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
            }
```