# Search Functions through Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm super stuck on this one guys and need some help.

I have a multiple arrays Name, age, height, weight which is created on another form where all their data is entered into the arrays but then I need to go to another form where there is text box that I enter one of the name into and click search and then in a text box or list box it will show age, height, weight corresponding to the index of that name search.

My main problem is trying to get the arrays data over to another form and the other problem is trying to get the computer to search through the array know what index it is and show the corresponding data to that index for the other arrays. Been stuck on this for very long now could some please give me suggestions on how to do this it would be heavily appreciated, Thank you.

This is the code/ arrays I have so far

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class DataEntry
    Dim Surname(200)
    Dim Firstname(200)
    Dim Age(200) As String
    Dim HeightA(200) As String
    Dim Weight(200)
    Dim index As Integer
    Public filepath As String = "c:\Patients\All Patients File"

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
        Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("c:\Patients")
        If di.Exists Then
            MsgBox("File is Already There")
            txtSur.Enabled = True
            txtWeight.Enabled = True
            txtHeight.Enabled = True
            txtFirst.Enabled = True
            txtAge.Enabled = True
            btnAddPatient.Enabled = True
            btnClear.Enabled = True
            btnFileShow.Enabled = True
            btnEdit.Enabled = True
            btnSave.Enabled = True
            txtReader.Enabled = True
        Else
            di.Create()
            MsgBox("File is Already There")
            txtSur.Enabled = True
            txtWeight.Enabled = True
            txtHeight.Enabled = True
            txtFirst.Enabled = True
            txtAge.Enabled = True
            btnAddPatient.Enabled = True
            btnClear.Enabled = True
            btnFileShow.Enabled = True
            btnEdit.Enabled = True
            btnSave.Enabled = True
            txtReader.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddPatient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddPatient.Click
        index = index + 1
        lblNum.Text = index
        Surname(index) = txtSur.Text
        Firstname(index) = txtFirst.Text
        Age(index) = txtAge.Text
        Weight(index) = txtWeight.Text
        HeightA(index) = txtHeight.Text
        Dim textAppend As String
          textAppend = txtSur.Text & ", " + txtFirst.Text & ", " + txtAge.Text & ",  " + txtHeight.Text & "mm" & ",  " + txtWeight.Text & "kg" & "."
        Try
            File.AppendAllText(filepath, textAppend)
            MsgBox("Patient Added Successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error Adding Patient")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFileShow.Click
        Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader("c:\Patients\All Patients File")
        txtReader.Text = objreader.ReadToEnd
        objreader.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Clear", "ALERT", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
        If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
            MessageBox.Show("Not Clearing")
        ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            MessageBox.Show("Clearing")
        End If
        Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\Patients\All Patients File")
        'adding text from textbox to text fil
        objwriter.Write("")
        objwriter.Close()
        Array.Clear(Surname, 0, Surname.Length)
        Array.Clear(Firstname, 0, Firstname.Length)
        Array.Clear(Age, 0, Age.Length)
        Array.Clear(Weight, 0, Weight.Length)
        Array.Clear(HeightA, 0, HeightA.Length)
        index = 0
        txtAge.Text = ""
        txtFirst.Text = ""
        txtHeight.Text = ""
        txtSur.Text = ""
        txtWeight.Text = ""
        txtReader.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataEntry_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtSur.Enabled = False
        txtWeight.Enabled = False
        txtHeight.Enabled = False
        txtFirst.Enabled = False
        txtAge.Enabled = False
        btnAddPatient.Enabled = False
        btnClear.Enabled = False
        btnFileShow.Enabled = False
        btnEdit.Enabled = False
        btnSave.Enabled = False
        txtReader.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
        If txtReader.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("No Infomation To Edit")
        Else
            txtReader.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        If txtReader.Text = "" Then
             MsgBox("Nothing To Save")
        Else
            Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\Patients\All Patients File")
            'adding text from textbox to text file
            objwriter.Write(txtReader.Text)
            objwriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Saved Edit")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the form I have to get the arrays over to for the search

```
Public Class SearchPatient
    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a class that holds these properties, create a list of these people, pass this list to your other form... That is some good suggestions. Also we help with specific problems and or issues, we wont do the work for you.

Comment: save the datas in a database, thats all

Comment: How do you usually get data from one place to another? Either you set a property or you call a method and pass an argument. This is no different. If you want to pass data into a form then that form needs properties and or methods that will accept that data. Note that a constructor is just a special method.

Comment: Getting data into forms and searching arrays are completely unrelated. Do not ask two unrelated questions in the same thread. Each thread is for a single question and you need to show us what you've tried. If you haven't tried anything then you haven't tried hard enough.

Comment: Rather than telling us a story about your code, why not post the code so you can get help rather than downvotes and/or close votes?

Comment: as @Codexer suggested use a list that holds class instances, you can read this answer to get the principles of how to pass the data to another form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085228/5718868